# hex сторка из файла в unsigned char* C++

Tags: c++, hex

Как из файла, где лежит файл вот такой примерный текст:

```
\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f
```

Получить в unsigned char* 
Как бы я получаю вот таким кодом

```
std::ifstream ifs(file);
std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
ifs.close();
har* hex = (har*)content.c_str();
```

Но есть разница, если я сделаю так

```
char *hex = "\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f";
cout << strlen(hex); // будет равняться 5
```

Но если из файла, то он как я понял читает все символы, и вопрос, как тогда получить из файла hex?
Заранее спасибо!

**EDIT:**

```
size_t ReadHexFile(FILE *inf, unsigned char *dest) {
    size_t count = 0;
    int n, u;
    if (dest == NULL) {
        unsigned int OneByte;
        while (true) {
            if ((n = fscanf(inf, "%hx", &OneByte)) == 1){
                count++;
            }else{ break; }

        }

    }
    else {
        while ((n = fscanf(inf, "%hx", dest)) == 1) {
            dest++;
        }
    }
    if (n != EOF) {
        ; 
    }
    return count;
}


unsigned char *file_get_contents(char *file){
    FILE *inf = fopen(file, "rt");
    int n = ReadHexFile(inf, NULL);
    rewind(inf);
    unsigned char *hex = (unsigned char *)malloc(n);
    ReadHexFile(inf, hex);
    fclose(inf);

    return hex;
}
```

Comment: Используйте функцию std::getline

Comment: В файле так прямо и лежат символы `'\'`, `'x'`,`'6'`,`'8'`? Или один символ с кодом 0x68?

Comment: Да вот так \x68

Comment: Это стандартное экранирование в шестнадцатиричном виде. Вот, например, как в ядре Linux решается эта задача: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=string_unescape

Comment: Я чуть изменил код, теперь у меня hex такого вида:
68 65 6c 6c 6f
И проверяю таким кодом,
(n = fscanf(inf, "%hx", dest)
Но есть проблема, когда встречается 00 (0x0), то он просто его не принимает. Как решить проблему?
Код в вопросе!

Comment: Ну зачем вы велосипед изобретаете? Эта же задача решается "в лоб", тут даже думать негде. Вот, что вас конктретно должно интересовать: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/string_helpers.c#L179

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код благополучно считывает 00, но, как я понимаю, просто дальше он воспринимается вашей программой как конец строки, только и всего... И, кстати, может, это вам и не нужно - но ваши функции не дописывают нулевой завершающий символ к считанной строке.

Еще - ваша функция при чтении в реальную строку возвращает 0, что нехорошо, на мой взгляд - допишите к `dest++` еще и `count++`.

А в конце, чтоб убедиться, что все читается - сделайте отладочный вывод `count` считанных символов в том же шестнадцатеричном виде.

Да, в `%hx` h оказывается лишним, это для чтения `unsigned short`: в первом случае его мало (вы читаете в `unsigned int`), во втором - много: вы читаете в `unsigned char`. Подумайте сами, как лучше читать. чтоб не нарваться на неприятности, если числа будут не из двух символов :)

Comment: Я проверил, да все считается, но почему то, когда я вывожу hex
То после 0x00 просто ничего не показывает. Так и не понял как решить проблему. 
И да, для char как я понял, нужен **%hhx**, так ли?
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Выводите не как строку, а как набор целых чисел. Как строка - вывод завершается, как только встречается нулевой символ.

Comment: Я уже приводил ТС как это сделано в известном проекте, там и парсинг, и создание, и дампы -- всё есть. Бери да пользуй!